# CSS grid with flex basis?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Current I'm doing

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(400px, 1fr));
```

But I want that when the view port is less than 400px the container should resize to the view port...
Or how do I implement Flex-basis property to grid... Where the minimum should be 0px but the container should start at 400px and then grow to 1fr

Comment: Why not use a `media` query?

Comment: isn't there any other way than media query????

Comment: Can't you show us an snippet as example? I didn't know if I undestand your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine what you have with `min()` and `100vw`. Less than `100vw` to avoid unwanted overflow and the `1fr` will do its job filling the remaining space. Any value bigger than `50vw` will do the job

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min(400px,80vw), 1fr));
  grid-gap:10px;
}

.container div {
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: any reason why you chose **80vw** ?

Comment: @thenoobslayer any value between 50vw and 100vw will do it. It need to be bigger than half the width to make sure you don't have two items side by side. I also avoided the 100vw to not have overflow so I picked 80vw :) it can be 70vw or 60vw ;)